# Order of Ajax call vs Script

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am trying to get a Navigation menu with this demo.

http://jqueryui.com/menu/

My issue is though the unordered list is coming from a Ajax call.Which i can see is successful.

this is the response of the Ajax call.

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
       <li>1.1</li>
       <li>1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My issue is the menu is not rendered correctly it just comes as list without any hierarchy.

My hunch is the following script is not run after the ajax call so menu is not correctly displayed

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu();
  });
  </script>
```

I am new to Ajax so any help even with lot of documentation will be helpful.

Here is the Ajax code. 'lhn' is where the navigation goes.

```
  jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        contentType: "application/xml",
                        dataType: 'html',
                        url: nav,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(xml) {
                                $("#leftnav").remove();
                                $("#lhn").append(xml);
                        }
           }
)
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Write the code in `.success()` method of ajax.

Comment: Its actually work related so i can't put the complete code but let me if i can put the relevant one.

Comment: Just show your ajax function.

Comment: @ShaunakD added the ajax call

Comment: Write `$( "#menu" ).menu();` after the `append(..)` line in ajax success.